# Copy image variable to a destination folder

Tags: python

I have dog images in img_data_color variable. I'm using for loop. That variable hold image iteratively. I would like to copy those images to the Dog folder. How can I perform that?

```
for num_color, data_color in enumerate(test_data_colorful[:12]):
    img_num_color = data_color[1]
    img_data_color = data_color[0]
```

I tried this one but it didn't work. Because, I want to copy image variable  to a folder. Not an image from a folder to another folder.

```
shutil.copyfile(source_test1, target_testDogs)
```

Comment: Why are you using `enumerate` but never using `num_color`?

Comment: I am using it in if else. Using Enumerate I am iterating the first 12 image elements in test_data_colorful array

Comment: If there is more relevant code, it would be worth showing. And enumerate is not necessary to limit yourself to the first 12 elements in the list. You're already doing that with `test_data_colorful[:12]`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70478523/writing-image-files-to-separated-folders-in-python

Check this out  please, my full code for it

Comment: What does "copy image variable image to a folder" even mean? Variables, no matter what they contain, don't reside in folders.

Comment: I have img_data_variable that contains image. I want to copy that image to a folder

Comment: check that stackoverflow link I shared to examine the whole part of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as any other variable.

```
with open("target.img", "wb") as f: # assuming it's a bytes
    f.write(img_data_color)
```